# Resetting MySQL auto-increment as tear-down step in Node.js unit test

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, node.js, express

I'm currently running unit tests on my DAL in a Node.js app. I'd like to be able to work with a dummy database, testing my CRUD operations with an informal setup/teardown that occurs throughout the test. Setup occurs by doing inserts, for example, and teardown by doing deletes.

I'm testing the database and not a mock/fake because I'd prefer to test complex SQL against a semi-working copy of the database.

The problem I'm running into is that on columns that have `AUTO_INCREMENT`-ing, I can't expect any consistency on IDs. By resetting the `AUTO_INCREMENT` I could avert this, but then I would be doing a lot of copy-paste coding, inserting a method in all my models.

Is there any way I can do this once and forget about it? Or is there a better practice I'm missing entirely?

Comment: I think the problems all stem from your statement "I'm testing the database and not a mock/fake " - what does this mean, exactly?  Why aren't you recreating the table from scratch as part of your test setup?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth This means that I'm actually connecting to a local version of MySQL, and not mocking it out. Maybe I should be doing both? Mocking the DAL for testing controllers and then testing the DAL separately as a sort of integration test.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I could certainly do that. And then just drop the table in the `tearDown`. That seems like an awful lot of work, though, when I could use the test itself to do the setup/teardown.

Comment: On second thought, using the test to do the setup/teardown seems like really bad practice, because expecting teardown to occur in a later test assumes the other tests pass. If they don't, then the teardown step may never occur properly.

Comment: Then I guess you should really be recreating the entire database from scratch as part of your setup.  That way there's no way you can be relying on state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use MySQL's [TRUNCATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) command, which empties a table and resets the AUTO_INCREMENT column. Effectively, it drops the table and recreates it which is faster than deleting all rows.